# Why does the spec for the "for attribute" of a <label> hints that an ID is not unique?

Tags: html, web-standards

We all know that in HTML, an element ID is (and must be) unique.

From the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute):

> The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character.

Yet in the same standard, the [`for` attribute in the `<label>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) element it reads:

> If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of the for attribute, and **the first such element** is a labelable element, then that element is the label element's labeled control.

That would mean there could be more then one element with an ID equal to the value of the `for` attribute.

So which is it? Unique - or not?

Answer (score 3):

It's covering the case where someone may not have made a unique id, since really there isn't anything hard preventing anyone from breaking standard, and specifies the behavior in such a case. Basically a secondary line enforcing the idea that there should only be 1 id with a certain value.

Comment: I'm really hoping for a less opinionated answer. Something that can at the very least be interpreted from the standard itself. If nothing comes up, I'll eventually accept this although it's not the type of answer I was after.

Comment: That's not going to happen as "web standards" are really an opinion of the browser interpreting them. There is absolutely nothing stopping a developer from using an id more than one time, except if the browser interpreters only target the first one encountered. That is exactly what the spec is recommending. It's not like there is a international committee that is policing this stuff and putting browser developers and developers alike for "breaking" the recommendation. Wish there was as without standards you get Microsoft...